# jQuery handle mouse events inside IFRAME

Tags: jquery

I am using Iframe for displaying book content (epub format).

I able to changing the book background color and book font-size.

But i am not able to call the event handlers inside IFRAME using jquery.

my javascript code is in the following way :

```
$('#bookcontentHeight').contents().find('body').bind("mouseup", function(e) {       
            alert('inside');
            e.preventDefault();         
            $("#custom-menu").css({ top: e.pageY + "px", left: e.pageX + "px" }).show(100);
        });
```

Comment: I solved the issue by using , var iframeDoc = $('#bookcontentHeight').contents().get(0);
  // Bind event to iframe document
  $(iframeDoc).bind('mouseup', function(e) {       
    e.preventDefault();     
    $("#custom-menu").css({ top: e.pageY + "px", left: e.pageX + "px" }).show(100);
  });

Answer (score 2):

Hope can work from these two option.

```
var iframe = $("#bookcontentHeight");
$(".body",iframe.get(0).contentDocument).mouseup(function(){alert('Hello')});
```

or

```
$("#bookcontentHeight").contents().find(".body").bind("mouseup", function() { alert("Hello"); });
```